# Show loading Blazor (webassembly) Assemblies/Dlls when the site is initially loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I am testing a Blazor Webassembly app and takes quite a long time to initially load (I did not use assembly trimmings and lazy loading)...And using the browser console, I noticed that a lot of assemblies/dlls are being downloaded first to the client every time the site is initially accessed (please see sample image below):

[image]

Is there a way to show the assemblies being downloaded in the "Loading..." of blazor app?
[image]

So that the user can see what the libs the app is initially downloading instead of just a spinner or staring to a static "Loading..." text?

Comment: Hi. Check this video about smaller and faster blazor app: youtube.com/watch?v=Jte_VwsSazs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using js to start Blazor, you can do this.

Blazor wasm allows you to customize startup behavior though js.

```html
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autostart="false"></script>
```

This will disable Blazor to startup immediately after the script is downloaded.
You can now then start blazor using the `Blazor` global variable.

```html
<script>
Blazor.start({
    loadBootResource: function (type, name, defaultUri, integrity) {
      const doc = document.getElementById("app"); // assuming you have <div id="app"> as the root component
      doc.innerHtml += `${name} ${defaultUri} <br />`;
    }
});
</script>
```

Returning `null` or `undefined` on `loadBootResource` will let Blazor's default download behavior do it's job. We're just hooking into it to get what's being downloaded.

more info on that on MS' docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0#load-boot-resources-1